# C++ Error handling and exceptions (situations where they could be useful)

Tags: c++

```
int main() 
{
    try
    {
        int a = 1;
        int b;
        cin >> b;
        if (b <= 0) throw b;
        int c = a / b;
        cout << c;
        
    }
    catch (int c)
    {
        cout << "You can't divide by zero.";
    }
}
```

Okay so I'm just now learning about error handling a bit and exceptions and well obviously here an exception is unnecessary right? I could also just put put some stuff in an if statement and else statement and that would also work wouldn't it? So I just wanted to ask does anybody have an example where it would be better to deal with errors with exceptions?
And another tiny question, I threw b here but would it be better to just make up some integer and consider that like the error code for this specific situation? Or what exactly should I be throwing? I guess if I wanna use the value that caused an error I should probably throw that?

Comment: Exceptions should only be used when the code that detects the problem can't solve it. So `if ... else ...` is the right approach in this simple example.

Comment: I've never seen anyone try to throw something that didn't inherit from exception. Without testing it, I'm fairly sure you can only throw exceptions not random data types.

Comment: I mean if I change the b to a 2 or something it still works the same, but so you're basically saying if I throw something it should be the thing that caused the error? Totally makes sense but I just wanna be 100% positive

Comment: @JosephLarson We can throw random data types in c++ https://godbolt.org/z/MThnP6Psb but I agree throwing expection is more readable.

Comment: @JosephLarson - Any (copyable) type can be thrown as an exception.    Deriving from `std::exception` (or its derived types) is a convention that a lot of programmers adhere to, but is not mandatory.

Comment: Whether or not the exceptions should be used at all, and if yes - where, are very hot topics with no clear answer. Especially in c++ where the implementation is... not the best.

One thing can be said for sure though: you absolutely should not throw something by hand only to catch it in the same scope. Just makes no sense, use ```if``` instead.

Comment: Different projects use exceptions with different discipline guidance.  My current project uses exceptions for flow control (I'm not happy with that).  My previous project used exceptions as "log the failure, panic save the user's project, terminate ASAP", so throwing any exception was tantamount to hitting the Big Red Button.  A former coworker disdained exceptions as being an invisible goto, making it impossible to reason about a program just by reading the code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.